# IIS7 auto rewrites when no trailing slash found

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

when I don't have a trailing slash IIS7 automatically does a redirect, how do I fix this..

so http://mydomain.com/deals
will redirect to http://mydomain.com/deals/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need to install the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite).

Then create a rule like this:

```xml
<rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])$"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
```