# Iis7 setting causing trailing backslash

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, trailing-slash

I'm experiencing a issue when i deploy the same MVC4 asp.net website to two different IIS7 servers.

On one box when i hit the "home" button for my website i get a trailing backslash and on the other i do not. The problem being , on the box that doesnt append a trailing backslash the jquery autocomplete doesnt work. When i add a backslash , it does. So this is the default behaviour i want. i.e. with backslash.

Both boxes have the same website , with the same web.config , neither iis server has url rewriting installed so i dont want to go down this route if i dont have to. It must be some different iis setting on one box to the other , but i have gone through each and not noticed any difference. Does anyone know offhand what could be causing this or point me in the right direction ?

Any help would be appreciated.

I know there are other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159359/iis7-auto-rewrites-when-no-trailing-slash-found) up here in the same area but none answer my question.

**Update:**

I have noticed a few questions on stackoverflow around **dots** in URLs causing backslashes, and i also realised that my server that adds the **trailing backslash** has a dot/period in it's address. So this looks like it might be causing my issue.

I suppose the correct thing would be to get it working with no trailing slash on both boxes. So now my issue is why is my jquery autocomplete not working on a address with no trailing backslash.

See [Question re: dots in urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

E.G:

```
http://localhost/MyPortal   
http://localhost/ARQ.MyPortal
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. To repair it on second server run Windows Update and install all. One KB fix this problem with IIS.